# xcode 5.1 - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (zbar)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, architecture

I have updated my x code version from 5.0 to 5.1
I have used ZBarSDK in my project for scan bar code. In simulator 'iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)' and 'iPhone Retina(4-inch)', it is working fine. But when i want to build with simulator 'iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)', it is giving the following error.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/sayan/Desktop/ProjectAtanu/Omlis/Custom Classes/ZBarSDK/libzbar.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/sayan/Desktop/ProjectAtanu/Omlis/Custom Classes/ZBarSDK/libzbar.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZBarReaderViewController", referenced from:
 objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
"_ZBarReaderControllerResults", referenced from:
-[HomeViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:] in  HomeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Architecture: Standard architecture(arm64, armv7, armv7s) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architectures: arm64,armv7,armv7s
Base SDK: Latest IOS(IOS 7.1)
iOS Deployment Target: iOS 6.1

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: did you solved this???

Answer (score 31):

**USING PODS**

```
pod 'ZBarSDK'
```

**OR**

Recompile ZBar for iphone 5. You can download recompiled ZBAR from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-p7lFlJim9YUFh6a3ZJWlNwQUU/view?usp=sharing) to skip the following

Steps

1. Download the source code (you must have [Mercurial](http://mercurial.berkwood.com/) for mac):
2. Open Terminal and run following commands

   a. hg clone http://zbar.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/zbar/zbar

   b. cd zbar

   c. hg checkout iPhoneSDK-1.3.1

   d. open iphone/zbar.xcodeproj
3. In the xcode project edit the "libzbar" scheme and select Release in Build configuration
4. Go to Build Settings set following Architectures

   a. **Architectures** - >Standard architectures(armv7,armv72,arm64)

   b. **Valid Architectures** -> arm64,armv7 armv7s
5. Compile libzbar for **device** AND for **simulator**, here the configuration:
6. Find the compiled libzbar.a and go in the folder using Teminal.app,

   In My Case : /Users/kappe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/zbar-gyozyrpbqzvslmfoadhqkwskcesd/Build/Products

   In this folder you you should have two sub folder Release-iphoneos and Release-iphonesimulator
7. using xcode command line tools build your universal lib:

   lipo -create Release-iphoneos/libzbar.a Release-iphonesimulator/libzbar.a -o libzbar.a

   Now you can use the libzbar.a created, both in device and simulator.

Ref : http://www.federicocappelli.net/2012/10/05/zbar-library-for-iphone-5-armv7s/

Comment: thanks but ... why not just share the result and save us the trouble? its not like the license won't allow it

Comment: Result : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-p7lFlJim9YUFh6a3ZJWlNwQUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For step #5 I used: (from the zbar/iphone folder extracted) ```xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release; xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release``` . Then step 6. ```cd build```

Comment: if you use cocoapod, this is solution.

Answer (score 2):

This implies the library is not supported/built for the new archtitecture.

For zBar [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12753812/1095089) has link to tutorial where you can download the source and just update the lib to new architecture.

Generally for a third party service. they will release new lib with the architecture added so make sure to check out their site for updated SDK.

Comment: Thanks Kabira for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Put in you Build Settings under "Other Librarian Flags" and "Other Linker Flags": $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)