# iOS static library can run on iphone5s ,but error on iphone4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

A static library can run on iphone5S,but have compile error on iphone4S.  What's the problem?
I have used  `lipo -info` command to check the static library.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How have you set your `Architectures` in Build Settings? You can have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26554428/3527656), on how to make you static library compatible with all architectures i.e. armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64.

Comment: I can't find it. Can you give me a link？

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552855/xcode-6-1-missing-required-architecture-x86-64-in-file/26554428#26554428

Comment: The static library support `armv7` architecture,why report `undefined symbols for architecture armv7` error?

Comment: Read this to understand the causes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6429568/3527656

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: I still have not found the solution.

Comment: Please don't paste an image... just copy the text of your errors...