# an error "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386"

Tags: ios, xcode6, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture

We have Xcode Version `6.1.1 (6A2008a)`.Resently my clinet send new project.it some one developed 45%.So then i code run on my Xcode i got errors like this

```
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386
```

After doing my R&D about this errors.Some one told changed Architectures in Xcode .Then i Changed like this

```
Architectures:Standard architectures(armv7,arm64)-$(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Build Active Architecture Only  NO
      Debug                             NO
      Release                           NO
Valid Architectures:arm64 armv7 armv7s
```

Please guide me how to solved this

My `OS X version 10.9.4` `Processor:2.5GHz Intel Core i5`

Comment: run your project in device

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik we tried about we got 2 erros like this 
1)Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PlanITOSClient", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in ServiceViewController.o

2)ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PlanITOSClient", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ServiceViewController.o 2)ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation

-- Means your class `ServiceViewController` file is missing

**type 1**

> Check if that file is included in Build Phases -> Compiled Sources

**type 2**

Make sure the ServiceViewController is a Target Member;

[image]

**type 3**

> your class "Format" is involved in the problem. Check your declaration of this class, especially if you did it inside an other class you probably forget the @implementation or some stuff like that

**type 4**

the above three types are not working fine please ref this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552855/xcode-6-1-missing-required-architecture-x86-64-in-file)