# Xcode 9.1 - Missing required architecture x86_64 in file

Tags: ios, xcode, x86-64

I am using the library [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) and having problems since the update to Xcode 9.1. I've recompiled the library with Xcode 9.1 and reimported the `.framework` in my Project. But I still can't use the classes from the library. I am getting this warning:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../Frameworks/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit.framework/SwipeCellKit, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/.../Frameworks/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit.framework/SwipeCellKit (2 slices)
```

I've tried what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552855/xcode-6-1-missing-required-architecture-x86-64-in-file) and set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No` when building the library. But it doesn't help. I've also cleaned the build folder many times, which doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: why are you not adding SwipeCellKit using Cocoa Pods?

Answer (score 0):

Please always use [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) to install libraries for your project, it will automatically manage all dependencies.

To setup you project for cocoapods please follow steps mentioned in http://cocoapods.org/ it will make your life easier believe me.

Once you setup cocoapods successfully,
then add

```
pod 'SwipeCellKit'
```

to your Podfile
and run terminal and goto your root project directory using cd ....
then type pod install
then open your root project folder using finder
and open YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace file and the issue will be gone gone,

let me know if you encounter any issue installing pods.
Thanks