# Xcode build error after swift 4 migration

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I have migrated my old working iOS project from Swift 2.3 to Swift 4, I am getting build failed with the error below:

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

and the warning below:

```
missing required architecture x86_64 in file ISHPullUp.framework/ISHPullUp
```

Note that:

- I have updated the project's carthage to the latest versions of frameworks.
- the framework I'm using and mentioned is [ISHPullUp](https://github.com/iosphere/ISHPullUp)
- I am getting this warning and error only when building for iPhone simulator unlike using iPhone physical device.

Am I missing something? 
thanks in advance

Comment: can you please run `file /path/to/ISHPullUP.framework` and paste the output in the question ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552855/xcode-6-1-missing-required-architecture-x86-64-in-file